# Autocompletion doesn't work when exectute 'sh script.sh /path/foo.py'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, autocomplete

I'm currently running under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

My problem is that when I run a script with the `sh` command wich need another file as argument like:

```
sh script.sh /path/foo.bar
```

the autocompletion doesn't work for the file `foo.bar`, I need to write it by myself. It works only if the extension is `.sh`. Otherwise, if I use the command `bash` instead of `sh`, the autocompletion works for any file extension.

I tried to add as first line of my `script.sh` the usual `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`, but nothing change.

I also re-link `sh` to `bash` instead of the initial `dash` : `ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh`

as a consequence `sh` would normally call `bash` and then works as identical ? But no.

I know that I could simply use `bash` as command and throw away `sh`, but ... you know :-)

==> So if you have any ideas to make `sh` able to autocomplete all file extention`, I'll appreciate !

Comment: This isn't really a programming question; perhaps you could try asking on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which completion function should be used is decided by the name of the command: `sh` not by the shebang line of anything or the link target of the command.

If you want to change that behaviour you need to adapt the complete function for `sh`. On Debian/Ubuntu it is located at `/usr/share/bash-completions/sh`

However, if you linked `sh` to `bash`, why don't you simply use `bash` instead of `sh`?

If you for whatever reason want to use `sh` instead of `bash` another dirty trick could be the following if it is good enough for you. Type:

```
+sh <tab-complete> <tab-complete>
```

now type `Pos1` and remove the leading `+` and then press enter.

Comment: I gave up with the auto completion so now I simply use `bash`. But anyway thanks for the dirty trick ;-)